# How to include usernames in mass emails php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Currently writing some php using mail() to send email to all users. The subject will be posted from the subject input field and the message will be posted from the message text area. The emails work and they send however how do I go around adding something like `%username%` so it will display the username of the user when they receive the emails?

I tried using `$user` when writing the email however the email just sends and displays `$user` rather than their username.

my code php:

```
if (isset($_POST['send-email'])){

    $subject = $_POST['subject'];        
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $lol = $odb -> query("SELECT * FROM `emails`");
    while ($show = $lol -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $email = $show['email'];
        $user = $show['username'];

        mail($email,$subject,$message,"From: Website <website@example.com>");
    }
}
```

html:

```
<form class="form-horizontal push-10-t" method="post">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="form-material">
                <label for="subject">Subject</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Enter subject here">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="form-material">
                <label for="message">Message</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" type="textarea" rows="10" id="message" placeholder="Please type your message here" name="message"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <button name="send-email" value="do" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" type="submit">Send</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

e.g.

```
Hello %username%,
```

We have updated our website... etc

Comment: We can't tell you what you're doing wrong if you don't show us the code where you're actually creating the message. I mean the part where you've tried including the username.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `%username%` in the actual message then use `str_replace` to replace that placeholder with the usernames.

Something like

```
str_replace('%username%', $show['username'], $message);
```

You need to use this approach because PHP is not going to execute a string as code. Consider what would happen if someone submitted the below string and it executed as code:

```
test '; exec('rm -rf /.');
```

That would hypothetically delete the whole server. Since it is a string though it is just stored as text and outputted or stored somewhere. (Note the storage of that string could be executed later, that is a second level injection and is a bit more complex than your question was asking. If you have that issue please ask another question about it.)

Comment: Great, please accept when the time has past. The variable version didn't work because strings aren't read as executable code, and that would be dangerous if it did.

Comment: @user3783243 Ok first of all, no green tic grabbing. OP is very well within his rights to wait for better answers before accepting one. Secondly, it completely depends on OP's code whether variables within a string are processed or not. If the string is withing double quotes, it'll work perfectly fine. Only within single quotes it won't.

Comment: The question is _unclear_. Hence my request to show the code where he's actually attempting to include `$user` in the first place. OP never did that. All you see is a HTML form and a `mail()` function that never includes the `$user` variable. Even _if_ it's the case where OP is trying to use `$user` in the form before submitting it, you should've explained that `$user` doesn't exist within that context. I'm not saying your answer is wrong, neither am I picking on you here. I'm just saying that answering _unclear_ questions is wrong, just as well as asking for an accept within a few minutes.

Comment: It's the way you worded it. If instead you said: "Please make sure to check the green checkmark next to the answer that helped you solve your issue. It's a way of showing your appreciation to the person that helped you out and makes sure your question doesn't remain unsolved forever.", no one would complain. As how you did it, it comes across as asking OP to accept your answer. Which is frowned upon. Anyway, as I said, I'm rly not a bad guy here. I suggest editing your answer and explain why it didn't work for OP. He'll probably won't return, but at least you'll get a +1 from me :)

Comment: Better. I asked because someone, somewhere in the future is going to come across this question and might want to actually learn something from your answer instead of just blindly copy / paste it. I mean, you can give someone the answer to a problem, but if you don't explain it, that same person is gonna ask again when a simular problem arises.